# How can I store events & their time in my application?(simulating recording sounds in a musical instrument app)

Tags: android, soundpool

I am developing an application with some buttons in it. When a button is touched, the application plays a sound with `SoundPool` method. Users can play music with this app like a piano app. For recording the rhythms, I want to store which sound was played and its exact time that user can play it later.
EX:

```
sound: S1    time: 00:01:45 (m:s:mls)
sound: S4    time: 00:01:93 (m:s:mls)
sound: S6    time: 00:02:05 (m:s:mls)    
sound: S2    time: 00:02:05 (m:s:mls)    
sound: S1    time: 00:03:25 (m:s:mls)    
sound: S5    time: 00:04:61 (m:s:mls)

...
```

Comment: you can use SharedPreferences or sqlite db for storing played sound file information

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Thanks. Main problem is how to play music from DB?

Comment: can u plz explain your problem to get more help

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK
How to save events and their times?(event is playing a sound)
How to play music from these events and times?

Comment: if im right you want to store last played time of sound in db any start it again from last played position ?

Comment: No. Consider a piano app. I want to implement recording in this piano app. to do this, I want to save which note(sound) was played and its time. how can I save this? and How can play it?